# Angular/TypeScript/RxJS - I've tried all renditions of map, concat, merge etc - trying to get nested items in array

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs

Currently the following final lines (after retrieving from an Observable.forkJoin of 17 this.http.get requests):

```
        .map(data => Observable.from(data))
        .finally(() => { console.log(this.topicData) })
        .subscribe((data) => { this.topicData = data });
```

And the console.log above you see gives me data in the following format:

[image]

As you can see, this has arrays within arrays.  I just want a single Observable array with the Objects nested two layers within shell arrays.  Again, I have tried all the maps, concat, reduce, merge etc.  With RxJS I feel like I just plug things in until it works.  When I read the documentation, I have difficulty understanding how it relates to what I am trying to do (training resources are welcome also).  For this problem in particular, does anybody know how I can return a single Observable array with the Objects?

Update with additional code from forkJoin:

```
return Observable.forkJoin(
            this.http.get(this.baseUrl + webs[0] + this.topicsRest, this.options).map((res: Response) => res.json().d.results),
            this.http.get(this.baseUrl + webs[1] + this.topicsRest, this.options).map((res: Response) => res.json().d.results),
            this.http.get(this.baseUrl + webs[2] + this.topicsRest, this.options).map((res: Response) => res.json().d.results),
            this.http.get(this.baseUrl + webs[3] + this.topicsRest, this.options).map((res: Response) => res.json().d.results),
            this.http.get(this.baseUrl + webs[4] + this.topicsRest, this.options).map((res: Response) => res.json().d.results),
            this.http.get(this.baseUrl + webs[5] + this.topicsRest, this.options).map((res: Response) => res.json().d.results),
            this.http.get(this.baseUrl + webs[6] + this.topicsRest, this.options).map((res: Response) => res.json().d.results),
            this.http.get(this.baseUrl + webs[7] + this.topicsRest, this.options).map((res: Response) => res.json().d.results),
            this.http.get(this.baseUrl + webs[8] + this.topicsRest, this.options).map((res: Response) => res.json().d.results),
            this.http.get(this.baseUrl + webs[9] + this.topicsRest, this.options).map((res: Response) => res.json().d.results),
            this.http.get(this.baseUrl + webs[10] + this.topicsRest, this.options).map((res: Response) => res.json().d.results),
            this.http.get(this.baseUrl + webs[11] + this.topicsRest, this.options).map((res: Response) => res.json().d.results),
            this.http.get(this.baseUrl + webs[12] + this.topicsRest, this.options).map((res: Response) => res.json().d.results),
            this.http.get(this.baseUrl + webs[13] + this.topicsRest, this.options).map((res: Response) => res.json().d.results),
            this.http.get(this.baseUrl + webs[14] + this.topicsRest, this.options).map((res: Response) => res.json().d.results),
            this.http.get(this.baseUrl + webs[15] + this.topicsRest, this.options).map((res: Response) => res.json().d.results),
            this.http.get(this.baseUrl + webs[16] + this.topicsRest, this.options).map((res: Response) => res.json().d.results)
        )
```

Comment: So you have an array of 17 positions, each position containing an array itself, and finally you want to concatenate/merge those 17 arrays into one? or did I missunderstand you question?

Comment: Those 17 arrays have additional arrays within them containing Objects.  The 17 arrays only contain arrays of objects.  I just one one array of the Objects at the second down of containing arrays.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. Here is the final code on the service function:

```
    return Observable.forkJoin(webs.map(web => 
        this.http.get(this.baseUrl + web + this.topicsRest, this.options).map((res: Response) => res.json().d.results)
    ))
        .flatMap(data => data.map(item => item.map(object =>  object )))
        .do(data => console.log(data))
}
```

Where webs is an array of relative site paths.  I did an async pipe on the ngFor of the template and it pulled through.  Thank you all for the references and help, it helped point me in the right direction.

Comment: Actually I lied, I realized this morning that the flatMap just removed the first layer of the 17 arrays.  When it hit the ngFor it was just looping through the first sub array so it was only 4 items.  I then did a .concatMap(data => data) to take all the objects out of the second set of array containers, then .toArray() to put all of those objects into an array.  It's working great now! :D

Answer (score 1):

Get rid of this line:

```
.map(data => Observable.from(data))
```

This is wrapping the observable in another observable, probably not what you were intending.

I agree that the Rxjs docs are frustrating! You might find rxmarbles.com  a helpful reference for some of the common functions, although it's not a good resource for first learning.

Hope I answered your question.

Comment: Thank you for the resource! I am looking at that now.  I removed that, and VS is giving me an error "any[] is not assignable to Observable <{}[]>. _IsScalar is missing...".  The console output is the same though.

Comment: Can you post more of your code, including the part with the forkJoin, and mention which line the error is occurring on?

Comment: What's the type of the `topicData` field?

Comment: topicData: Observable<{}[]>;

Comment: If topicData is an observable then you shouldn't be subscribing at all. Something like this should suffice: `this.topicData = Observable.forkJoin(...);`

Comment: Yes it does work, however it does not allow me to access the properties I need via the view.  It is just returning the array as the item that I am iterating through in the ngFor loop.  I need the object.  When I do this line below the forkJoin, I see the object I want being logged ".map(data => data.map(item => item.map(object => console.log(object) )))"

Answer (score 0):

I tried something different to your approach, basically I flat the collections into a single array. Check:

http://plnkr.co/edit/c6lwtmYC91Yj4ji80CEa

```
interface Data {
  text: string;
  val: number;
};

// this could be a service method
method(): Observable<Data[]> {
    let example: Observable<Data[]>;
    const webs = [1, 2, 3];
    //created fake Observables with test data
    const source = forkJoin(webs.map(val => of<Data[]>([{ text: '1rst', val: val + 1 }, { text: '2nd', val: val + 2 }])));
    example = source.mergeMap(data => data).mergeMap(data => data).toArray();
    return example;
  }
```

With this you will get an Observable that emits a single array with all the elements in the different arrays.

Hope it helps!